# How to fix: when overlaying two scatter plots with using reorder of aes, the reorder gets lost

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two scatter plots obtained from two sets of data that I would like to overlay, when using the ggplo2 for creating single plot i am using log scale and than ordering the numbers sothe scatter plot falls into  kind if horizontal S shape. Byt when i want to overlay, the information about reordering gets lost, and the plot loses its shape.

this is how the df looks like (one has 1076 entries and the other 1448)

```
protein  Light_Dark       log10
AT1G01080   1.1744852  0.06984755
AT1G01090   1.0710359  0.02980403
AT1G01100   0.4716955 -0.32633823
AT1G01320 156.6594802  2.19495668
AT1G02500   0.6406005 -0.19341276
AT1G02560   1.3381804  0.12651467
AT1G03130   0.6361147 -0.19646458
AT1G03475   0.7529015 -0.12326181
AT1G03630   0.7646064 -0.11656207
AT1G03680   0.8340107 -0.07882836
```

this is for single plot:

```
p1 <- ggplot(ratio_log_ENR4, aes(x=reorder(protein, -log10), y=log10)) +
  geom_point(size = 1) + 
  #coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 1000)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0.1, col = "red") + #check gene
  geom_hline(yintercept=-0.12, col = "red") +#check gene
  labs(x = "Protein")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+
  labs(y = "ratio Light_Dark log10")+
  labs(x="Protein")
image=p1
ggsave(file="p1_ratio_data_ENR4_cys.svg", plot=image, width=10, height=8)
```

and for over lay:

```
p1_14a <- ggplot(ratio_log_ENR1, aes(x=reorder(protein, -log10), y=log10)) +
geom_point(size = 1) +
#coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 1000)) +
geom_hline(yintercept=0.1, col = "red") + #check gene
geom_hline(yintercept=-0.12, col = "red") +#check gene
labs(x = "Protein")+
theme_classic()+
theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
axis.text.x=element_blank(),
axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+
labs(y = "ratio Light_Dark log10")+
labs(x="Protein")+
geom_point()+
geom_point(data=ratio_log_ENR4, color="red")





p=ggplot(ratio_log_ENR1, aes(x=reorder(protein, -log10), y=log10)) +
  geom_point(size = 1) +
  #coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 1000)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0.1, col = "red") + #check gene
  geom_hline(yintercept=-0.12, col = "red") +#check gene
  labs(x = "Protein")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+
  labs(y = "ratio Light_Dark log10")+
  labs(x="Protein")
p = p + geom_point(data=ratio_log_ENR4,  aes(x=reorder(protein, -log10), y=log10), color ="red" )
p
```

I tried to change classes... but it cant be the problem since for single plot its working like it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution I see for you is just binding together your two dataframes before plotting.

```
a$color <- 'red'
b$color <- 'blue'

ab <- a %>%
  rbind(b)

ggplot(ab, aes(x = fct_reorder(protein, -log10), y = log10, color = color)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_identity()
```

You can find a nice cheat-sheet for working with factors here: https://stat545.com/block029_factors.html